# how can i get the failures details about phpunit and phing results

Tags: phpunit, phing

[phpunit] Tests run: 415, Failures: 13, Errors: 19, Incomplete: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.19617 s

i wanna find out the details about failures and errors,how do?

Comment: possibly related: http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/655

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your build file?

In any case, to have the phpunit task output additional information, use the 'plain' formatter in the task call:

```
<phpunit ...>
    <formatter usefile="false" type="plain"/>
    <batchtest>
    ...
    </batchtest>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: thx everybody
these r my build code


`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="noah3" basedir="." default="test">
<target name="test">
<phpunit haltonfailure="true" printsummary="true">
<batchtest>
<fileset dir=".">
<include name="**/*.php"/>
</fileset>
</batchtest>
</phpunit>
</target>
</project>
`